# Error when upgrading from V2 in alpine js

Tags: alpine.js

I am trying to upgrade (version 2 --> 3) and I have checked all (I think) breaking changes  from the list found in the [docs](https://alpinejs.dev/upgrade-guide#breaking-changes).

However, I am still getting an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_x_effects')`

My code is originally based on [this snippet](https://alpinetoolbox.com/examples/pagination), so it'd be easier to reproduce it from there (the error appears there too if you replace the script tag in the head to: `<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>` )

Below the code to which the link above points to:

```html
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>

<body class="bg-grey-100 px-3 font-sans leading-normal tracking-normal">
  <div class="container pt-8 mx-auto" x-data="loadEmployees()">
    <input
      x-ref="searchField"
      x-model="search"
      x-on:click="viewPage(0)"
      x-on:keydown.window.prevent.slash=" viewPage(0), $refs.searchField.focus()"
      placeholder="Search for an employee..."
      type="search"
      class="block w-full bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:shadow text-gray-700 font-bold rounded-lg px-4 py-3"
    />
    <div class="mt-4 grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
      <template x-for="item in filteredEmployees" :key="item">
        <div
          class="flex items-center shadow hover:bg-indigo-100 hover:shadow-lg hover:rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 p-3"
        >
          <img
            class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full mr-4"
            :src="`${item.profile_image}`"
          />
          <div class="text-sm">
            <p
              class="text-gray-900 leading-none"
              x-text="item.employee_name + ' (' + item.employee_age + ')'"
            ></p>
            <p
              class="text-gray-600"
              x-text="'$'+item.employee_salary/100"
            ></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>

    <div
      class="w-full md:w-1/2 mx-auto py-6 flex justify-between items-center"
      x-show="pageCount() > 1"
    >
      <!--First Button-->
      <button
        x-on:click="viewPage(0)"
        :disabled="pageNumber==0"
        :class="{ 'disabled cursor-not-allowed text-gray-600' : pageNumber==0 }"
      >
        first
      </button>

      <!--Previous Button-->
      <button
        x-on:click="prevPage"
        :disabled="pageNumber==0"
        :class="{ 'disabled cursor-not-allowed text-gray-600' : pageNumber==0 }"
      >
        prev
      </button>

      <!-- Display page numbers -->
      <template x-for="(page,index) in pages()" :key="index">
        <button
          class="px-3 py-2 rounded"
          :class="{ 'bg-indigo-600 text-white font-bold' : index === pageNumber }"
          type="button"
          x-on:click="viewPage(index)"
        >
          <span x-text="index+1"></span>
        </button>
      </template>

      <!--Next Button-->
      <button
        x-on:click="nextPage"
        :disabled="pageNumber >= pageCount() -1"
        :class="{ 'disabled cursor-not-allowed text-gray-600' : pageNumber >= pageCount() -1 }"
      >
        next
      </button>

      <!--Last Button-->
      <button
        x-on:click="viewPage(Math.ceil(total/size)-1)"
        :disabled="pageNumber >= pageCount() -1"
        :class="{ 'disabled cursor-not-allowed text-gray-600' : pageNumber >= pageCount() -1 }"
      >
        last
      </button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div
        class="mt-6 flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700"
      >
        <div
          class="w-full sm:w-auto text-center sm:text-left"
          x-show="pageCount() > 1"
        >
          Page <span x-text="pageNumber+1"> </span> of
          <span x-text="pageCount()"></span> | Showing
          <span x-text="startResults()"></span> to
          <span x-text="endResults()"></span>
        </div>

        <div
          class="w-full sm:w-auto text-center sm:text-right"
          x-show="total > 0"
        >
          Total <span class="font-bold" x-text="total"></span> results
        </div>

        <!--Message to display when no results-->
        <div
          class="mx-auto flex items-center font-bold text-red-500"
          x-show="total===0"
        >
          <svg
            class="h-8 w-8 text-red-500"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="2"
            stroke="currentColor"
            fill="none"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          >
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
            <line x1="9" y1="10" x2="9.01" y2="10" />
            <line x1="15" y1="10" x2="15.01" y2="10" />
            <path d="M9.5 16a10 10 0 0 1 6 -1.5" />
          </svg>

          <span class="ml-4"> No results!!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var sourceData = [
      {
        id: "1",
        employee_name: "Tiger Nixon",
        employee_salary: "320800",
        employee_age: "61",
        profile_image: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
      }, // etc.
    ];

    function loadEmployees() {
      return {
        search: "",
        pageNumber: 0,
        size: 10,
        total: "",
        myForData: sourceData,

        get filteredEmployees() {
          const start = this.pageNumber * this.size,
            end = start + this.size;

          if (this.search === "") {
            this.total = this.myForData.length;
            return this.myForData.slice(start, end);
          }

          //Return the total results of the filters
          this.total = this.myForData.filter((item) => {
            return item.employee_name
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
          }).length;

          //Return the filtered data
          return this.myForData
            .filter((item) => {
              return item.employee_name
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            })
            .slice(start, end);
        },

        //Create array of all pages (for loop to display page numbers)
        pages() {
          return Array.from({
            length: Math.ceil(this.total / this.size),
          });
        },

        //Next Page
        nextPage() {
          this.pageNumber++;
        },

        //Previous Page
        prevPage() {
          this.pageNumber--;
        },

        //Total number of pages
        pageCount() {
          return Math.ceil(this.total / this.size);
        },

        //Return the start range of the paginated results
        startResults() {
          return this.pageNumber * this.size + 1;
        },

        //Return the end range of the paginated results
        endResults() {
          let resultsOnPage = (this.pageNumber + 1) * this.size;

          if (resultsOnPage <= this.total) {
            return resultsOnPage;
          }

          return this.total;
        },

        //Link to navigate to page
        viewPage(index) {
          this.pageNumber = index;
        },
      };
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's working fine for me with AlpineJS 3 after fixing a `:key` error (replacing with `:key="item.id"`). Could you create e.g. a codesandbox that reproduces your error message?

Comment: Indeed, I'd missed that, thanks!